# Holomorphic mapping on a manifold approximating a constant map

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds, several-complex-variables

Let $X,Y$ be complex manifold, $Y$ Stein. It sounds quite reasonable to formulate the following claim: given $y_0\in Y$, for every $\epsilon>0$ and $M\subset X$ compact, there exists an holomorphic mapping $h\colon X\to Y$ with dense image (that is $\overline{h(X)}=Y$) such that
$$
\|h-y_0\|_M<\epsilon
$$
(the distance is taken with respect some Riemannian metric on $Y$).

This sounds like a very standard result; can somebody provide a reference? Or suggest some counter example, but I think this fact holds true. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just take the constant map, equal to $y_0$?

Comment: Constant maps between complex analytic spaces are holomorphic.

Comment: Because I was tired and I forgot to add that I need $h$ to have dense image. Apologies. I'm going to edit

Comment: This fails (with the modified question) for example for $X$ compact and $Y=\mathbb{C}$. To have dense image certainly restricts which $X$ and $Y$ for which it is possible.

Comment: Even if both X, Y are Stein this fails. Maybe if X is a complex disk and Y is connected this holds.